# Fancytree Drag and drop of Node outside a frame

Tags: drag-and-drop, fancytree, html5-draggable

I loaded fancytree in a frame1 with Drag and drop capabilities.I am having a frame2 with Droppable traget;cureently I am not able to move the fancy tree node out of the frame1 at all.
I am able to drag and drop with in facnytree with in frame1 ONLY.

Please suggest how to do that?
Somthing like HTML 5 drag and drop ....of fancytree nodes on any where/any iframe/frame....does fancy tree supoorts that?
IF not;what is the tweak for that?

Answer (score 0):

By default draggable node in tree create in parent component, if you want drag to other frames you should specify you'r parent component **appendTo: "body"**
For my it's work:

```
     dnd: {
        draggable: {
            zIndex: 1000,
            scroll: false,
            revert: "invalid",
            appendTo: "body"
        },
 }
```